# How to render template with python json as treeview?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I need to render an html template with flask.
I have a dict in python and I want to show it in a treeview.
How can I do it?

I found this resource: https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview
that could be useful, but I can't use it.

```
dict_var = {
    "test3@test3.com": {
        "discord_id": 0,
        "status_key": False,
        "username": "test3@test3.com",
        "last_name": "aaaa",
        "gender": "male",
        "email": "test3@test3.com",
    },
    "test9@test9.com": {
        "username": "test9@test9.com",
        "last_name": "test9",
        "gender": "male",
        "discord_data": {
            "user": {
                "avatar": None,
                "discriminator": "111",
                "verified": True,
            },
            "connections": [],
            "guilds": [
                {
                    "icon": "hellohellohellohello.jpg",
                    "id": "222222222222",
                },
                {
                    "icon": None,
                    "id": "111111111",
                    "owner": True,
                }
            },
            "email": "hello@hello.com",
            "activation_key": "hello-hello-hello-hello-hello",
            "first_name": "hello@hello.com",
            "discord_id": 22222223333334444,
            "state": "IT"
        }
    }
```

flask function for render template

```
@app.route('/test')
def test():
   return render_template('test.html', res=dict_var)
```

test.html

```
...

<div class="container">
    <div id="tree"></div>

<script>
    $(function() {
  var mytree = JSON.parse('{{ res|safe }}');

  $('#tree').treeview({
    data: mytree
  });
});
</script>


...
```

how to pass res to js and convert the dict to treeview?

Comment: your `json_var` isn't JSON, it's a Python dictionary. (It can easily be converted to and from JSON, but you likely don't need to do that, especially if you're already passing it as a template variable.) As for what to put in your template, that all depends on what information you're trying to display from that dictionary, and how - you really don't make it clear what you want.

Comment: yes, I'm wrong. I edit the code. Where is the problem now? @RobinZigmond

Comment: I'm not familiar with "treeview" - but the one thing I do notice is that, since you're calling `JSON.parse` on `res`, it needs to actually *be* JSON. For this, you need to pass it to the template as `json.dumps(dict_var)`.

Comment: @RobinZigmond It doesn't work. But do not raise errors

Comment: well, "it doesn't work" isn't very helpful - and I really have no idea what you're trying to do. (As I've said, I've never come across this "treeview" before.) However from a quick glance at the docs it seems to say the data needs to be an array, and yours is an object.

Comment: @RobinZigmond sorry for my explanation but I don't know js so I'm a little confused.
I try to add `[]`to dict_var. like this: `dict_var = [{
    "test3@test3.com": {
        "discord_id": 0,
....
 "discord_id": 22222223333334444,
            "state": "IT"
        }
    }]`The result appears to be one row, not clickable [image](https://ibb.co/YtGzh0s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tojson`.

```
...


<div class="container">
    <div id="tree"></div>

<script>
    $(function() {
  var mytree = JSON.parse('{{ res|tojson }}');

  $('#tree').treeview({
    data: mytree
  });
});
</script>


...
```